# Rails: Passing a local variable to a simple_form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am trying to link to a simple_form page and pass a string to the subject field. My code is

```
%li.item.ask= link_to "Ask a question about this product", contacts_path, :locals => { :subject => "Question about the #{@product.name}" }
```

But the field is not populated on the form.

Comment: do you want to send params from link_to?

Comment: yes thats right, I have a link on the product page and I want the link to pass the product.name to the simple_form page

Comment: `<%= link_to "Ask a question about this product", contracts_path(product_name: product.name) %>` and then on your form access it as `params[:product_name]`

Comment: is it working for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help. That looks ok as a solution but sometimes the contact form is used a a general contact form and wouldn't have a product name in there. Also I would prefer to have the full text 'Question about the XYZ Product'

Comment: `<%= link_to "Ask a question about this product", contracts_path(subject:"Question about the #{@product.name}") %>` try this